# Can I use bootstrap3 classes in bootstrap 4 version(panel, pull-right, col-xs-4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Here We have one confusion.
Can I use bootstrap3 classes in bootstrap 4 version
Example:  panel, pull-right, col-xs-4
in my excising project. I used these classes. can I go with same or replace with new classes(panel-card).

Comment: No, you can use Bootstrap 4 classes with Bootstrap 4. [Read about migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/).

Comment: Thanks Zim..
But in my current project I have 300+ HTML pages.
If I migrate it(V3 to V4). I have to replace or re write All pages.
Here I need shortcut or  Easy way to use BOOTSTRAP4 without disturbing my excising code

Comment: Again, you need to **read the migration docs**. There is no "shortcut" that's going to migrate 300+ pages of v3 code. Do the research, and there are [tools that will help](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) but it *is* a major rewrite. If you attempt to use Bootstrap 3&4 together there will be conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4-

(1) panels, wells, and thumbnails have been replaced by cards.

```
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
<div class="card-body">
<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

(2) pull-left and pull-right are replaced by float-left and float-right.

(3) .col-xs-4 is now .col-4